# Não aparecem erros no VSCode (ex: erros referenciando algo digitado de forma errada)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

Já olhei em tudo que tinha e não consegui ainda...

Estou estudando ASP.NET Core, com C#, e não aparecem os erros no Visual Studio Code.

Exemplo: se eu referenciar uma classe com o nome errado, não dá alerta nenhum.
Onde posso arrumar isso?
(Os erros de estrutura aparecem)

[image: Como nessa imagem, em tempo de desenvolvimento o VSCode não acusa nenhum erro]

O erro:

Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details.

Source: C# (Extension)

```
   [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\Vanessa\Desktop\Engenharia de Computação\Estágio\SSTecnologia\2-DotNETCore\ProAgil.Domain\ProAgil.Domain.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\Vanessa\Desktop\Engenharia de Computação\Estágio\SSTecnologia\2-DotNETCore\ProAgil.Domain\ProAgil.Domain.csproj'.
c:\Users\Vanessa\Desktop\Engenharia de Computação\Estágio\SSTecnologia\2-DotNETCore\ProAgil.Domain\ProAgil.Domain.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: o SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' especificado não pôde ser encontrado.  c:\Users\Vanessa\Desktop\Engenharia de Computação\Estágio\SSTecnologia\2-DotNETCore\ProAgil.Domain\ProAgil.Domain.csproj
   em Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   em Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   em OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath) na D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:linha 129
   em OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath) na D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:linha 72
   em OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader) na D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:linha 98
   em OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) na D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:linha 308

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\Vanessa\Desktop\Engenharia de Computação\Estágio\SSTecnologia\2-DotNETCore\ProAgil.API\ProAgil.API.csproj
```

Comment: Por padrão, o VSCode não detecta os erros mesmo. Quem detecta os erros é a IDE do Visual Studio. Mas você pode ter a detecção de erros no Code, tem uma extensão que faz isso, mas não sei ao certo o nome dela.

Comment: Ainda não consegui, alguma ideia?

Comment: instalou a extensão?

Comment: Não consegui achar nenhuma extensão sobre isso... já tenho algumas instaladas, mas como estou aprendendo a usar o VSCode agora não sei muito bem qual seria

Comment: @Vanessa Alves, verifica se você tem a extensão *C# for Visual Studio Code (OmniSharp)* instalada no VSCode: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp)

Comment: Tenho instado a extensão sim. Já procurei em todo lugar pra resolver isso e não consigo

Answer (score -1):

Seus pacotes instalados provavelmente estão dando conflito nas versões, procure instalar todos da mesma versão e verifique se a versão do sistema bate com o sdk instalado no seu pc.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: caso tenha instalado as versões erradas, tente dar um update para a versão mais atual, exemplo: dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.0

Answer (score -2):

Galera eu também estava com este problema, porém eu estava acostumado a apenas abrir a pasta e clicar em abrir com visual studio. Depois de muita luta descobri que se abre o projeto executando o arquivo .sln a partir disso funcionou normalmente, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).